# Entropy change of the environment during water condensation

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, condensation

When water vapor condenses, the entropy of the water decreases, since
$\Delta S=\int{\frac{dQ}{T}}=\frac{mL}{T}$ and $L<0$. Since this process is reversible, the environment must have an entropy increase with the same magnitude. How does this happen? Do the air molecules around the water heat up?

Comment: Think about how you cool down on a hot day. You sweat, and the sweat while evaporating pumps the necessary heat out of you, cooling you down. Condensation is quite literally the reverse. It pumps some heat in. You have yourself used the quantity L, which is the latent heat of fusion. You can consider what this quantity represents, and what kind of energy exchange it implies for fusion or condensation

Comment: To do it reversibly, the surroundings should consist of an ideal infinite reservoir which acts as a heat sink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since this process is reversible, the environment must have an entropy
> increase with the same magnitude.

The process is only reversible if (1) the temperature of the surrounding air is kept infinitesimally less than the temperature of the water vapor (<100$^o$C) and (2) the heat capacity of the air must be large enough so that its temperature doesn't change when heat is transferred to it (i.e., it must be a constant temperature thermal reservoir). If these conditions are met, then yes, the positive change in entropy of the air equals the negative entropy change of the water.

> Do the air molecules around the water heat up?

If by "heat up" you mean does the temperature of the air increase, then the answer is no because it has to meet condition (2) above. In other words, the transfer of heat to the air occurs isothermally (at constant air temperature). That will be the case if the mass of air is great enough so that the amount of heat transferred to it does not change its temperature.

Hope this helps.